# Pandas frequency/count - new df versus new column in exisitng df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df_original`:

```
        Date         Latitude   Longitude   lat_round  lng_round   
0       2017-02-06   25.1978    55.2816     25.198     55.282  
1       2017-02-06   25.2707    55.3740     25.271     55.374  
2       2017-02-06   25.2581    55.3291     25.258     55.329  
256864  2017-02-05   25.0835    55.1425     25.084     55.143  
256865  2017-02-05   25.2278    55.3273     25.228     55.327
```

I wish to cluster these records by rounding the `Latitude` and `Longitude` records down (`lat_round` and `lng_round` respectively). Presently, I am doing this by creating a new dataframe `df` via:

```
df = df_original.groupby(["lat_round","lng_round"]).size().reset_index(name="frequency")
df = df.sort_values(by='frequency',ascending=False)
```

I then get the dataframe, `df`:

```
      lat_round  lng_round  frequency
0     25.245     55.361       5138
1     25.248     55.353       1907
2     25.249     55.352       1820
3     25.197     55.281       1293
```

However, since I wish to actually extract all individual records (with full Lat, Lng resolution) this isn't very useful. How do I append a column to the original dataframe with the frequency, based upon the `lat_round` and `lng_round` records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df_original, df, on=['lat_round','lng_round']))
         Date  Latitude  Longitude  lat_round  lng_round  frequency
0  2017-02-06   25.1978    55.2816     25.198     55.282          1
1  2017-02-06   25.2707    55.3740     25.271     55.374          1
2  2017-02-06   25.2581    55.3291     25.258     55.329          1
3  2017-02-05   25.0835    55.1425     25.084     55.143          1
4  2017-02-05   25.2278    55.3273     25.228     55.327          1
```

Another solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df_original.groupby(["lat_round","lng_round"]).size()
df.name='frequency'
print (df)
lat_round  lng_round
25.084     55.143       1
25.198     55.282       1
25.228     55.327       1
25.258     55.329       1
25.271     55.374       1
Name: frequency, dtype: int64

print (df_original.join(df, on=['lat_round','lng_round']))
              Date  Latitude  Longitude  lat_round  lng_round  frequency
0       2017-02-06   25.1978    55.2816     25.198     55.282          1
1       2017-02-06   25.2707    55.3740     25.271     55.374          1
2       2017-02-06   25.2581    55.3291     25.258     55.329          1
256864  2017-02-05   25.0835    55.1425     25.084     55.143          1
256865  2017-02-05   25.2278    55.3273     25.228     55.327          1
```